# Webpack code splitting for java portlet development

Tags: reactjs, webpack, liferay, portlet

I am currently in the process of building an application on the Liferay java open source portal platform, and running into some issues configuring my webpack to work optimally with React across a large project structure.

Liferay has the concept of a theme, which contains all of the JS/CSS that is needed across any page on the site, and also portlets, which are self contained modules which can be placed on certain pages (portlets have their own JS which is separate from the theme).  My webpack works great for my theme JS, but I would like to use the same copy of react for each webpack bundle instead of including a copy with every portlet. However, when I attempt to do this, I get an error about ReactDOM not being defined.

Liferay has a very opinionated project structure as follows:

```
    -root
        -modules
            -my-portlet
                -src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/
        -themes
            -my-theme
                -src/js/
```

Webpack file for my theme (in the my theme folder):

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var REACT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/react');
var JS_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            path.resolve(REACT_DIR, 'Bootstrap.js'),
            path.resolve(JS_DIR, 'Utility.js')
        ],
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'react-dom',
            'react-addons-css-transition-group',
            'react-animate-height',
            'react-google-maps',
            'react-overlays',
            'react-redux',
            'react-scroll',
            'react-sticky',
            'redux',
            'redux-thunk',
            'shortid'
        ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                include: [
                    path.resolve(JS_DIR)
                ],
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(REACT_DIR, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js', Infinity)
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

My portlet's webpack (in the my portlet folder):

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var JS_SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js/src/');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(JS_SRC, 'main.js') // Your appʼs entry point
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ['babel'],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        // Use external version of React
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: './src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js/dist'
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you placing js files in src? You can directly put them under `docroot/js` for portlet and `docroot/_diffs/js` folders.

Comment: We are developing for liferay DXP, they have changed the file structure for themes/portlets.